# How to add number before a word inside a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this menu inside a text file:

```
#Menu 1 file
Jelly Fish Yee Sang with Pear
Dried Seafood with Fish Soup
Steamed Sea Water Grouper
```

and I have this code:

```
menuList = input('enter number:')
def printPackage(menuList):
    if menuList == '1':
        with open('menu/Menu1.txt')as f:
            data = f.read()
            print(data)
printPackage(menuList)
```

What should I add to my code so that I have my text file to print like this?

```
---------
Menu List
---------
1. Jelly Fish Yee Sang with Pear
2. Dried Seafood with Fish Soup
3. Steamed Sea Water Grouper
```

Help please.

Comment: iterate on the file lines & use `enumerate` to get an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
menuList = input('enter number:')
def printPackage(menuList):
    if menuList == '1':
        with open('menu/Menu1.txt')as f:
            lines = []
            for l_i, line in enumerate(f.read().split('\n'), 1):  # Read the file and split it on newline. Enumerate the results returning index (l_i) and the line. Start l_i at 1
                formatted_line = '%s. %s' % (l_i, line)  # Format it with the line number.
                print(formatted_line)
                lines.append(formatted_line) 

            # If you want to save it.
            with open('menu/Menu1_with_numbers.txt', 'w') as o_f:
                o_f.write('\n'.join(lines))  # Join back the lines on newline and write it out to Menu1_with_numbers.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation. Helps a lot

Comment: What should I change to the program if I want only specific word line inside the text file? Example there are 1. A  2. B  3.C inside the text file....How to get only 1. A or 1.A and 2.C where the C change to number 2

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Pythonic WAY** ( MUCH FASTER ):

```
get_input = input('Enter Number: ')
if not get_input == "1":
    exit()
write_save = open("menu/result.txt", "a")
read_lines = [write_save.write("{}. {}{}".format(counts, line.rstrip("\n"), "\n")) for counts, line in enumerate(open('menu/Menu1.txt'), 1)]
write_save.close()
```

**Or Even Shorter :**

```
get_input = input('Enter Number: ')
if not get_input == "1":
    exit()
read_lines = [open("result.txt", "a").write("{}. {}{}".format(counts, line.rstrip("\n"), "\n")) for counts, line in enumerate(open('Menu1.txt'), 1)]
```

**JUST ONE LINE ( LOOL )** :

```
if input("Enter Number: ") == "1" : [open("result.txt", "a").write("{}. {}{}".format(counts, line.rstrip("\n"), "\n")) for counts, line in enumerate(open('Menu1.txt'), 1)]
```